# Clion warns about glm::dot returnType but compiles anyways

Tags: c++, opengl, clion, glm-math

```
GLfloat test = glm::dot(glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f),glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
```

This compiles and works fine but the Clion-IDE insists that there is an error.

> Types 'GLfloat' and 'glm::highp_vec3' are not compatible.

Do i have to supress the warning or is there a more elegant way to go about this.

Comment: I want to just say I have the same problem, however sometimes it works, and sometimes it doen't depending on the GLM verision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CLion** unfortunately chose to implement its own C++ parser ([using ANTLR](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Third-Party+Software+Used+by+CLion)) and it is not perfect, although it's getting better. So the reason for the inspection warning in such cases when the compiler compiles the code successfully is that the CLion parser makes a mistake somewhere. Your compiler is a better source of understanding C++ since... well, it's a compiler.

To turn the inspection warning off, you can do one of the following:

> ### Suppressing inspections in the editor
>
> 1. Set the cursor to the highlighted code issue in the editor.
> 2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or click the light bulb icon intentionBulb to expand the suggestion list.
> 3. Depending on the issue, you will see either quick-fixes related to the inspection or the Inspection "" options item.
> 4. Use the up/down arrow keys to select this item and then press the right arrow key or just click the right arrow  rightArrowInMenu next
>      to this item. Pressing the left arrow key, or Escape hides the
>      suggestion list.
> 5. In the inspection options list, select the desired suppress action: The inspection will be suppressed with special comments in the
>      corresponding piece of code.

or

> ### Suppressing inspections from the Inspection tool window
>
> 1. After running code analysis, select a code issue, for which you want to suppress the inspection, in the Inspection tool window.
> 2. Click hectorBack on the toolbar of the Inspection tool window, or just right-click the selected inspection.
> 3. Choose the desired suppress action. For example: The inspection will be suppressed with special comments in the corresponding piece of
>      code.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/suppressing-inspections.html

Comment: OK then i will simply supress those warnings. Just wanted to make sure i am not missing some Template parameters. Thanks!